# GoogleSheet Formula to Bring Back GoogleNews

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Looking for a GoogleSheet formula that will bring back

1. UNIQUE HEADLINES, off GoogleNews specifically by keyword "Tesla"
2. with Publication Date sorted by ASC
3. Limit 20 headlines
4. Then, I want to group headlines by dates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `=IMPORTFEED()` function in Google sheets, and use `sort` and `unique` to make sure that you do not have duplicate titles and that they are sorted by date.

First, you need to construct the Feed URL of Google News using this format:

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=<KEYWORD>
```

For this case, I used:

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Tesla
```

After that you need to construct the formula:

```
=IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Tesla")
```

*Note: By default, you will get the first 20, so the basic =Importfeed() formula will work*

To sort the information, since the format of the date is odd, it cannot be sort directly. So I use this formula in the `E1` cell:

```
=INDEX(IF(C1:C20="",,REGEXREPLACE(C1:C20," GMT","")*1))
```

Lastly, I create a new sheet (name the last one "raw") to sort the date on this one:

```
=SORT(raw!A1:E20,5,true)
```

It will look like this:
[image]

**Reference:**

- [ImportFeed fuction.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337)
- [Sort Function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [Unique Fuction.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)

Comment: [@helpmeplease](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19684007/helpmeplease) If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Instead of the creating another tab. Can you force the sort to happen on the same sheet? I see you trying to sort the date but when I try it it doesn't even sort correctly. It scrambles the dates and doesn't show by specific asc or desc order.

Comment: This is the sort result: 

8/10/2022
8/10/2022
8/9/2022
8/9/2022
8/4/2022
7/28/2022
7/14/2022
7/18/2022
8/5/2022
8/3/2022
7/19/2022
8/10/2022
8/8/2022
7/25/2022
7/21/2022
7/16/2022
8/5/2022
8/10/2022
7/18/2022
8/10/2022

Comment: Let me check about the sort. Also, I tried to sort it into the same sheet, and I was not able to do so. However, I can see if I can find anything.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the sheet you are using? Since I created a new sheet and pasted the formulas, and the sort is working for me.

Comment: [@HelpMePlease](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19684007/helpmeplease), I tried to sort the information in the same sheet, but I was not able to do so.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. We ended up going with your solution to place it on separate sheets. Weird that it won't work on the same sheet. Thank you again!

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of news results coming back? I think google news default is 20 records. What if we only want 10 records? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use the following formula: 
`=IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Tesla","","",10)`

Comment: Or use:
`=IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Tesla","","true",10)`. If you want to add the headers.

Comment: Thank you so much! As you can see I'm a beginners. Is it possible to query by certain keywords in the headlines? Like I still want to query by the "Tesla" keyword but I only want to bring back headlines with certain keywords like "Sweden" or "European Union" etc.

Comment: mmm.. not sure. Maybe if you modify the feed URL, you can see some options to change the URL [here](https://www.aakashweb.com/articles/google-news-rss-feed-url/), or you can use [this option](https://rss.app/rss-feed/google-news-rss-feed) of Google News feed to generate the link for you.

Comment: Hello again - how can I limit the Google News query to bring back only unique Title (even if publisher is different). For example, I only want one of the following headlines: 
The Sun is Bright - New Yorker
The Sun is Bright - New York Times